# Does sharepoint use static urls

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Say if I have the following files `img1.png`, `foo.pdf,` I have a sharepoint site `sharepoint/project/folder/images`. If I add the `img1.png` would the url look as follows `sharepoint/project/folder/images/img1.png`. I ask this because I have a database with references to documents name `img1.png`. I will upload these document to sharepoint I should be able to prefix all the documents row data with `sharepoint/project/folder/images/`. When user enters this url it would take them to their reference image. Does sharepoint work in this way?

NB: I dont have a sharepoint account

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SharePoint uses static URLs in the way you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The url are accessible until and unless library is present and url till ".../images/" folder is intact in structure....

As your database is external, it depends on how you save this url/path reference in database column value, i think it should be always absolute url rathen then relative url...

Answer (score 0):

Links are meant to be broken, at least if you move files or change file names of documents in SharePoint.

I had a customer that required links not to be broken when the file name was changed, or a document was moved. They also wanted to be able to create links to a specific version, current version, and the latest major version. The idea was by using the document context menu. Users would have the option to create these URLs.